# Sybase sql statement

Tags: sybase

I have Sybase database 15 and one of oracle query wanted to convert into sybase Database.

I have tried all option but not able to find google so i need your help

```
select Log_record_id,
  Event_time,
  SUBSTR (Object_of_reference,(LOCATE (Object_of_reference, '=', 1, 2) + 1),((LOCATE (Object_of_reference, ',', 1, 2) - LOCATE (Object_of_reference, '=', 1, 2)) - 1)) as NENAME,
  Perceived_severity,
  Specific_problem,
  '' as Cease_time,
  Alarm_id,
  SP_text,
  Alarm_state 
from FMA_alarm_list 
where  Log_record_id > 63314472
```

Getting Error

> Msg 14216, Level 16, State 1: Server 'SYBASESERVER', Line 1: Function
>   'INSTR' not found. If this is a SQLJ function or SQL function, use
>   sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce a
>   large amountof output).

Comment: You have posted the Oracle SQL, can you also post the converted Sybase SQL that is producing the error?

Comment: the same error is getting the posted query after converted from Oracle to Sybase . Actually, I wanted to select only new row added from Sybase server.

Comment: Which Sybase product as LOCATE for example isn't valid syntax on some Sybase database products.